# How best to crack password for MacOS encrypted .dmg, given I know the majority of the password content?

Tags: encryption, password-cracking, macos

Encrypted .dmg on MacOS High Sierra, tested password before sending for repair. Upon return from repair, password does not work. The possibilities I see are the .dmg file is corrupted, or I'm wrong about the password I thought I knew.

Nothing else seems corrupted so am tentatively assuming the latter.

In that case, as far as I can tell I could be wrong only about a minority of the password content.

Is there a way to discover the password given I have knowledge of the majority of its likely content?

Answer (score 3):

- **Concerning corruption:** Do you have a copy of this encrypted .dmg in your Time Machine backup?
- **Concerning entering your password manually:** Have you typed your password out in to a text editor to ensure you are typing the password correctly?  Once you have verified the password in the text editor just copy and paste the password into the dialog box for the encrypted .dmg. Try this method with any possible passwords.
- **Brute forcing the password dialog box:** You could try to brute force the password using one of the many utilities for such purposes.  Here is a list of some the scripts:

  1. https://github.com/alfanhui/dmgCracker
  2. https://calvin.me/cracking-passwords-on-macos
  3. http://www.georgestarcher.com/software (sadly this doesn't support your OS).

Here is a nice blog post about the complexity of cracking the password of an encrypted .dmg.

https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage

Comment: Thanks. No copy of the .dmg in Time Machine. I have used a text editor. Regarding brute forcing, it will be impossible unless I can enter the majority of the password and check for variations around that. I think the John the Ripper option allows that, but in the second link I see it cracks the hash rather than the password. Do you know if that means my knowledge of the password is not useful?

Comment: The second option still uses John the Ripper, which is a hash cracker.  Most password crackers use a brute force attack against the hash of the password.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm ignorant of encryption. Do you know if the fact that it's a hash cracker means that partial knowledge of the password is irrelevant? Or is that knowledge still usable when cracking the hash?

Comment: Most password hash crackers can either brute force the hash with zero knowledge of the password.  These crackers can also be programmed to use either a custom character set or a portion of a know element of the password being cracked.  Password cracking is an art form and requires some trail and error to get right.